# Log4j2 logging configuration not creating a log file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, log4j, log4j2

For a very basic spring-boot application, I am trying to log into a log file using log4j2 yaml configuration. But no log file is created. I have tried to look around but none of the solutions seem to work.

**The pom file has the following dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**The code where logging is done (also the only code in application):**

```
import com.example.demo.model.DemoData;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@Log4j2
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Value("${messageFromProperties}")
    private String messageFromProperties;

    @Value("${messageFromYaml}")
    private String messageFromYaml;

    @GetMapping("/demo")
    public ResponseEntity<DemoData> getDemoMessage(){

        DemoData demoData = new DemoData(messageFromProperties, messageFromYaml);
        log.error("ERROR!!!");
        log.debug("DEBUG!!!");
        log.info("INFO!!!");

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(demoData);
    }
}
```

**The properties file:**

```
messageFromProperties: Message from properties
messageFromYaml: Message from YAML!!!

logging:
  config: classpath:log4j2.yml
```

***log4j2.yml* file contents. File present in "resources" directory**

```
Configuration:
  status: debug

  appenders:
    RollingFile:
      - name: LogToRollingFile
        fileName: "logs/demo.log"
        filePattern: "logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/demo-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 10MB
        DefaultRollOverStrategy:
          max: 10

  Loggers:
    logger:
      - name: com.example
        level: debug
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: LogToRollingFile
    Root:
      level: debug
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: LogToRollingFile
```

I see contents being printed in console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

17:25:49.535 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR com.example.demo.controller.DemoController - ERROR!!!
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can put the logger configuration in a separate XML file then you can try this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="debug_logs" value="logs/debug_logs"/>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level --- [%12.12thread] %-50logger{36} : %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${debug_logs}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level --- [%12.12thread] %-50logger{36} : %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${debug_logs}/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                     class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!--Max Size of each file to start Archive -->
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    
            <!-- Days till log history to keep -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>150MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    
    </appender>
    
    
    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Once you put this configuration (`logback.xml`) in the same directory as your `applciation.properties`, you can use the `@Slf4j` annotation (provided by Lombok) on top of your class and use the log object to log anything you want.

You should be able to see your logs in a folder (in the same directory as your project) at `/logs/debug_logs/debug.log`, if everything works well.